# Toggling links in menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

How to make that the links can works only with sub-items?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="item-1">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="item-1-1">item 1.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="item-2">Item 2</a></li>

    <li><a href="item-3">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="item-3-1">item 3.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="item-3-1-3">item 3.1.1</a></li> <li><a href="item-3-1-2">item 3.1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I did a very basical example.

```
$('ul').on('click','a',function(){

    if ($(this).next('ul').toggle()) return false;

});
```

This might toggling links with sub-items and if the link hasn't them than go to location in the href, but wont work, why?

```
ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
```

actually, here is the fiddle: [nested menu](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/dEgBp/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `.toggle()` will *never return* a *falsy* value even if it is called on non-existent elements. This means your `if` condition `if ($(this).next('ul').toggle())` will always *pass*.

Change it to:

```
$('ul').on('click','a',function(){
    if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEgBp/2/)**